# How can I add JSP syntax highlighting to Komodo Edit?

Tags: jsp, configuration, syntax-highlighting, komodoedit

I am editing a JSP using the Komodo Edit. I need help in order to add jsp(*.jsp) to Komodo Edit's file association list?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hack to add syntax highlighting:

- Close Komodo
- Find [keywords.py](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/blob/master/src/silvercity/PySilverCity/SilverCity/Keywords.py) in your [installation directory](http://community.activestate.com/faq/komodo-file-locations)
- Choose a supported language with similar elements, then replace its keywords with your own.
- Restart Komodo, open a file of that type, then update the [color preferences](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/prefs.html#colors) and [use a macro to debug](http://community.activestate.com/faq/debug-udl-language-styling) your changes.

The formal process is to use the [Luddite language](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/8.0/udl.html).

Answer (score 1):

Some of you may find (or actually in this case, not find) keywords.py in the latest 8.5.3 build (Komodo Edit). Regardless it's fairly straight forward in the GUI:

From the top menu goto: Komodo > Preferences > File Associations

Add the "pattern" you wish to associate (*.jsp) in the Patterns box under New Association, select the language from the dropdown that you want to associate the pattern with, then click "Add..." to add it to the list.

Note that the file association is not saved to your pattern until you click "Ok" at the bottom of the Preferences dialogue.